# Fill values in dataframe by matching column names to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I need to map the values of a dictionary to the names of the columns of a dataframe. If there is no value I would like to fill up the dataframe with zeros

```
import pandas as pd
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Chat','Email','Phone','VM','web','Sum unique values', 'Date', 'Time', 'Month Selected', 'Year Selected'])
export_dict ={'Chat': 1, 'Email': 4, 'VM': 15}
```

Result:

```
Chat Email  Phone VM web Sum unique values Date Time Month Selected Year Selected
 1    4      0    15  0         20          0     0    0               0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new row to DataFrame by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
final_df.loc[0] = export_dict
```

and then replace misisng values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
final_df = final_df.fillna(0)
print (final_df)
   Chat  Email  Phone  VM  web  Sum unique values  Date  Time  Month Selected  \
0     1      4      0  15    0                  0     0     0               0   

   Year Selected  
0              0
```

Another solutions are with DataFrame costructor for improve performance - here is added all columns by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
export_dict ={'Chat': 1, 'Email': 4, 'VM': 15}
c =['Chat','Email','Phone','VM','web','Sum unique values',
   'Date', 'Time', 'Month Selected', 'Year Selected']

final_df = pd.DataFrame([export_dict]).reindex(c, axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (final_df)
   Chat  Email  Phone  VM  web  Sum unique values  Date  Time  Month Selected  \
0     1      4      0  15    0                  0     0     0               0   

   Year Selected  
0              0
```

Or by `merge` of dictionaries, order is important of passed value - need first zero dict for avoid overwrite values by `0`:

```
final_df  = pd.DataFrame([{**dict.fromkeys(c, 0), **export_dict}])
print (final_df)
   Chat  Email  Phone  VM  web  Sum unique values  Date  Time  Month Selected  \
0     1      4      0  15    0                  0     0     0               0   

   Year Selected  
0              0
```

If change order all values are `0`:

```
print ( pd.DataFrame([{**export_dict,**dict.fromkeys(c, 0)}]))
   Chat  Email  VM  Phone  web  Sum unique values  Date  Time  Month Selected  \
0     0      0   0      0    0                  0     0     0               0   

   Year Selected  
0              0
```